Finding the $p$- adic representation of $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{7}{4}$.
I want to solve the following Problems:
Show that $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{7}{4}$ are Elements in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ ($5$-adic integers) and calculate the first four coefficients of the power series representation.
My approach:
I will start with $\frac{1}{2}$.
By the formula for the geometric series we know that $\frac{1}{1-q}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q^k$.
I can write $-\frac{1}{2}$ as $2 \frac{1}{1-5}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2 \cdot 5^k$.
Since the coefficients of the power series are constant we know that $-\frac{1}{2}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.
Since $1 \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ (because $1=1 \cdot 5^0+0 \cdot 5^1 +...$) and because $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a ring we get that $1+(-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}_5$.
To calculate $\frac{1}{2}$ I can use the power series of $1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$.
Thus $\frac{1}{2}=(1 \cdot 5^0+0 \cdot 5^1 + 0 \cdot 5^2+...)+ (2 \cdot 5^0 + 2 \cdot 5^1 +2 \cdot 5^2+...)=3 \cdot 5^0 +2 \cdot 5^1 +2\cdot 5^2+... $.
Next up is $\frac{7}{4}$:
I can write $\frac{7}{4}=1+\frac{3}{4}$.
Then $-\frac{3}{4}=3\frac{1}{1-5}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 3 \cdot 5^k$.
Now since $1$,$-1$ and $-\frac{3}{4}$ are 5-adic, so is $\frac{7}{4}=1+(-1)(-\frac{3}{4})$.
And for the power series I get $\frac{7}{4}=1+(-1)(-\frac{3}{4})=((-2) \cdot 5^0+(-3)\cdot 5^1+(-3)\cdot 5^2+...)$
I did compare my solutions to the solution of the Problem and for $\frac{1}{2}$ I get the same solution but for $\frac{7}{4}$ my solution is different. The solution of the exercise should have been $3 \cdot 5^0 +1 \cdot 5^1 +1 \cdot 5^2+...$.
I can't figure out what I did wrong in the second exercise. As far as I can see I did the exact same thing.
So my questions are:
Where is my mistake in the second part?
How does one calculate the $p$-adic representation of a number $\frac{a}{b}$?
I thought that one would calculate the series for $-\frac{1}{b}$
and then calculate $a \cdot (-1) \cdot (-\frac{1}{b})$?

@J.W.Tanner Yes right. I will edit it

If you want to do it the way you did, try using $\frac74=2-\frac14$.  For $p$-adic numbers, the coefficients should not be negative

@J.W.Tanner With $\frac{7}{4}=2-\frac{1}{4}$ I get the correct solutio $2+5+5^2+...$.

Do you know why my approach did not work?

I hope you mean $\color{red}3+5+5^2+\dots. $   And as I said, the coefficients should not be negative

$\frac{7}{4} = (-2)\cdot 5^0 + (-3)\cdot 5^1 + (-3)\cdot 5^2 + \cdots$ is a valid equality, it's just not the canonical form the question is asking for.  If you add $0 = 5\cdot 5^0 + (-1)\cdot 5^1$, you get $\frac{7}{4} = 3\cdot 5^0 + (-4)\cdot 5^1 + (-3)\cdot 5^2 + \cdots$.  Then, add $0 = 5 \cdot 5^1 + (-1) \cdot 5^2$ to get it equal to $3\cdot 5^0 + 1\cdot 5^1 + (-4)\cdot 5^2 + (-3)\cdot 5^3 + (-3)\cdot 5^4 + \cdots$, and so on.

What do you think the power series representation of $-1$ is?

@TorstenSchoeneberg I would say it is $-1 \cdot 5^0 +0 \cdot 5^1 +0 \cdot 5^2 +...$.

canonical form would be $4\cdot5^0+4\cdot5^1+4\cdot5^2+\cdots$

Blessedly, it seems to be more and more common to write $p$-adic numbers as $p$-ary expansions, running (potentially) infinitely to the left. The digits will be in the range $0,\dots,p-1$. So, this way of displaying $1/2$ five-adically comes out to $\dots22223;$, and $7/4$ is $\dots11113;$ . Once you write your numbers this way, you can do addition, subtraction, and multiplication exactly as you learned to do in elementary school. Division proceeds right to left too, so it feels somewhat different to your familiar long division. But it works very nicely. I recommend it.

Note:  $\frac74=\left(\frac12+1\right)/2+1$

What @J.W.Tanner said. More generally, for any prime $p$, the "standard" way to expand $-1$ (with coefficients from $0,1, ..., p-1$) is $$(p-1) \cdot p^0 + (p-1) \cdot p^1 + (p-1) \cdot p^2 +\dots,$$ a nice application of geometric series.

And by the way, the by far best write-up on expansion of rationals as $p$-adics I know is Keith Conrad's https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/rationalsinQp.pdf

@TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you! I will have a look at it.

Your answer is not really wrong, but, because you have negative coefficients,
it's not in the canonical form, where all coefficients are between $0$ and $4$, inclusive.
As pointed out in a comment by Daniel Schepler,  $\frac{7}{4}=1+(-1)\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)$
$=(-2) \cdot 5^0+(-3)\cdot 5^1+(-3)\cdot 5^2+...$
$=3\cdot5^0+(-4)\cdot5^1+(-3)\cdot5^2+\dots$
$=3\cdot5^0+1\cdot5^1+(-4)\cdot5^2+\cdots=3\cdot5^0+1\cdot5^1+1\cdot5^2+\cdots$, by borrowing.
You could get to the canonical form more directly by taking $\frac74=2+\left(-\frac14\right).$
Another way to compute $\frac74$ in $\mathbb Z_5$ follows:
mod $5:  \frac74\equiv\frac{7+5}4=3$
mod $5^2:  \frac74\equiv\frac{7+25}4=8$
mod $5^3:  \frac74\equiv\frac{7+125}4=33$
mod $5^4:  \frac74\equiv\frac{7+625}4=158$
You can see the pattern:   mod $5^n:  \frac74=\dfrac{7+5^n}4$
and $\dfrac{7+5^n}4=\dfrac{2\cdot5^0+1\cdot5^1+5\cdot5^{n-1}}4=\dfrac{2\cdot5^0+1\cdot5^1+5^{n-1}}4+5^{n-1}$
$=\dfrac{2\cdot5^0+1\cdot5^1+5^{n-2}}4+5^{n-2}+5^{n-1}=\cdots=\dfrac{2\cdot5^0+2\cdot5^1}4+5^1+\cdots+5^{n-2}+5^{n-1}$
$=3\cdot5^0+5^1+\cdots+5^{n-2}+5^{n-1},$
which becomes $3\cdot5^0+1\cdot5^1+1\cdot5^2+\cdots$ in $\mathbb Z_5$ as $n\to\infty$.
